# Portals in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, virtual-reality, webvr

Hi has anyone been able to make a portal type thing in ThreeJS?

I want to play with impossible architecture for my thesis on VR, I've been trying to make for example a small square house that when you look through the door you see that inside the house is an impossibly large hallway that couldn't possible fit in the house.

I wanted to do it by making a 'portal' on the door that connects to another scene, and I tried doing it with rending a camera on to a texture like this example ( http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html ) and by using .setViewOffset to try to crop into it, but I'm just getting very lost. and it isn't working...

Any help would greatly be appreciated; http://sanschaise.com/thesis is what I currently have..

Comment: Getting "File Not Found" on your thesis URL. Are you still having this issue?

Comment: ahh I had to give up on that, this is whats up so far [link](http://avirtualspace.xyz)

Comment: MetaRoom Markup will support this eventually. It is a markup language for VR. `<meta-room> <meta-wall><meta-door src='#other -room'> </meta-wall></meta-room> ` https://github.com/MetaRoomMarkup/MetaRoomMarkup

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let you know, for the portals I did the rendering also with the [camera to texture](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html) demo from Stemkoski.

I dont understand your exact problem or what you experienced, but its totally do-able:
[image]

Also the portals are actually working and teleporting the player :)

Comment: Great work! Is the code for the demo pictured in your answer available online?

Comment: Its an ancient project before Ive started to use github or knew how to javascript, but you can run it at http://three.thiele-medien.de/threejs-r71/examples/igod.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! Works great in Firefox, some strange errors crop up in the Javascript console in Chrome, though.